# I am trying to create image slider.When i access images through "document.getElementsByClassName" and if i print its length in console it return 0

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to HTML CSS. I am trying to create image slider.When i access images through `document.getElementsByClassName` through javascript objects and if i print its length in console it return 0. And I need to move those images from right to left smoothly. I tried using `translateX` property. Is there any other way to do that. I don't know what's gone wrong?

```js
function slider() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("image-container");
  for (i in x.length) {
    x[i].style.transform = "translateX(-90%)";
  }
}

slider();
```

```css
.content {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  height: 85vh;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  padding: 0px;
}

.inner-content {
  padding: 75px 50px 0px;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cont {
  flex: 1.5;
  padding: 90px 0px 0px 50px;
  background: chocolate;
}

.cont h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 1px 0px black;
}

.cont p {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.cont button {
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 11%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid #072085;
  color: #072085;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.image-container {
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

.image-container img {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  animation: drop 1.5s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-page">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner-content">
      <div class="cont">
        <h3>Redmi Note 8</h3>
        <p>48MP AI rear camera with Sony IMX586 camera sensor</p>
        <button href="#">BUY NOW</button>
      </div>
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="1.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!----2nd-->
    <div class="inner-content">
      <div class="cont">
        <h3>Redmi Note 8</h3>
        <p>48MP AI rear camera with Sony IMX586 camera sensor</p>
        <button href="#">BUY NOW</button>
      </div>
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="1.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!----3rd-->
    <div class="inner-content">
      <div class="cont">
        <h3>Redmi Note 8</h3>
        <p>48MP AI rear camera with Sony IMX586 camera sensor</p>
        <button href="#">BUY NOW</button>
      </div>
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="1.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `for (i in x.length)`? You want to iterate over `x`, not its length.

Comment: for(i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++ )
    {
        x[i].style.transform="translateX(-90%)";
    } doesn't provide result.If i print its length in console by using x.length it returns 0

Comment: Try to do a console.log(x) to understand. Maybe it couldn't find the elements.

Comment: The example you posted works

Comment: @Thanh Trung.I tried printing console.log(x).It returns HTMLCollection[] under that it shows length as 3.But when i try to print x.length it returns zero.

Comment: @skyline3000 How?

Comment: Try to modify your snippet. I'm sure there is no case where x.length is 0. Do console.log(x.length) right after getting x